# Redirect (301) Random Urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

How do I redirect (301) URLs that are random like /search.php?tag=Classy using .htaccess method. I tried below one which didn't work.

```
Redirect 301 /search.php?tag=Classy http://www.domain.com/tag/classy/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Redirect rule looks fine. As long as this is the .htaccess in the root of your website, it should find it. However, you need to also make sure you have the **mod_alias** module enabled in your instance of Apache, which you probably do.

I made a mistake earlier, but yes, if you have RewriteRules, you will need the following:

`Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On`

.. and you mentioned Rewrites are indeed working.

The other possibility is that your Rewrites are overlapping with your Redirects. mod_rewrite directives will execute prior to mod_alias, regardless of the order in your .htaccess.

Comment: I tried adding your suggestion but it didn't work. **mod_rewrite** is enabled. Though when I try
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]` it work but it redirects to `domain.com/?tag=Classy`

Comment: I added a little bit, mentioning that any rewrite directives you may have added could be overriding the redirects you want to perform. I would recommend you post more of the .htaccess if you're still having trouble. And if not, post what fixed it!